# Using subprocess in a curses application

Tags: python, subprocess, curses

I'm creating an application that uses `curses` to build a simple user interface. It also uses the `subprocess` module to run external text editor so a user can type some text, then close the editor and go back to the main program.

The problem is that when the editor is console-based such as Vim or Nano, curses doesn't de-initialize properly. Which means if the color mode is used (`curses.start_color()`), terminal stays colored after the program is finished.

Here's a test script that has this issue (at least for me, I use Ubuntu and gnome-terminal):

```
import curses
import subprocess

screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
screen.keypad(1)
try:
    curses.curs_set(0)
except curses.error:
    pass
curses.start_color()

screen.addstr(0, 0, 'hello, world!')
screen.refresh()

while 1:
    c = screen.getch()
    if c == ord('q'):
        break
    if c == ord('r'):
        subprocess.call('vim', shell=False)
        screen.clear()
        screen.addstr(0, 0, 'hello, world!')
        screen.refresh()

curses.nocbreak()
screen.keypad(0)
curses.echo()
curses.curs_set(1)
curses.endwin()
```

(Press `r` to enter Vim, then `q` to exit.)

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would modifying your code to:

```
if c == ord('q'):
    subprocess.call('reset', shell=False)
    break
```

be enough for you? Or is there some additional behaviour in your real script that is not in the code you pasted here, that makes this workaround unsuitable to your goal?

Comment: It works, but I think it's not really nice to reset a user's terminal like that, losing all the scrollback etc. But if I don't find a better solution, I'll use this, thank you.